# sql query friend of friend

Tags: sql, mysql

I know how to get mutal friends in 1 query but now comes the hard part, how can i get all my friends friends which are not allready my friends in 1 query that returns the users id's? I have looked at some of the posts here regarding this but i couldnt get them to work as i wanted.

My relationsships are two way so that if 1 and 2 are friends, there exists two rows in the relations table.

my tables with relevant info:

```
table_users
user_id
```

---

```
table_relations
rel_id
from_id
to_id
```

I have strugled with this for 2 days now, and i cant seem to get it to work.

Best of regards,
Alexander

Comment: Some databases have extensions for helping with queries like this. If you can/are willing to step away from "standard SQL" and provide more information -- e.g. specify which engine -- then another class of answers may emerge ;-)

Comment: mysql is the only database i have used, what do u suggest i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an `id` of 1

```
/*Your friends' friends*/
SELECT r2.from_id FROM
table_relations r
INNER JOIN table_relations r2
ON r.from_id = r2.to_id
WHERE r.to_id = 1
EXCEPT /*EXCEPT is Standard but MINUS in Oracle*/
/*Your friends*/
SELECT from_id
FROM table_relations
WHERE to_id = 1
```

Or using an `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT r2.from_id
FROM
table_relations r
INNER JOIN table_relations r2
ON r.from_id = r2.to_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_relations r3 ON r3.to_id = r2.from_id AND r3.from_id=1
WHERE r.to_id = 1 AND r3.from_id is null
```

Comment: i couldnt get this to work, i got error which said mysql_fetch_array expects 1 as parameter

Comment: @Alexander - MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT`. `NOT IN` would be the closest equivalent though I think `OUTER JOIN` might be more efficient. You need to tag your RDBMS or I for one will assume standard SQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Friends
SELECT to_id
  FROM table_relations
 WHERE from_id=ME;

# Friends of Friends
SELECT to_id
  FROM table_relations
 WHERE from_id IN (
       SELECT to_id
         FROM table_relations
        WHERE from_id=ME
       );

# Friends of Friends, not my friends
SELECT to_id
  FROM table_relations
 WHERE from_id IN (
         SELECT to_id
           FROM table_relations
          WHERE from_id=ME
       )
       AND
       to_id NOT IN (
         SELECT to_id
           FROM table_relations
          WHERE from_id=ME
       );
```

I'm sure there's a way to make this more efficient with temporary tables, but this should get you going.

Comment: the last one returns
68
68
68
68
68
68
68
68
10

where 10 is the friend of friend not my friend, and 68 is my id, should i just make another condition here?

Comment: You could put a `DISTINCT` in there if you're getting unwanted dups.

Comment: i just did AND to_id != ".$_SESSION['user_id'].", 68 was the id i was testing, 'ME'

Answer (score 0):

find all your friends, find all the friends friends. Then, use a `NOT IN` to find the difference.

```
select user_id
from
(
   select user_id from ... --select all the friends friends
) as friends_friends

where friends_friends.user_id not in
(
   select from_id from  
     from table_relations
     where MYID=to_id 
)
```